# Check if a set of string is contained in a string

Tags: angular, string, typescript, string-comparison

I'm facing a problem with Angular/Typescript, but it can be applied on the most of programming languages.

I have a huge text that we will call **fulltext** and a set of **filters** that are applied on fulltext and know if they match; let me explain better:

suppose our fulltext is something like this

> "Hello there! My name is Mattia"

and the filters are

> ["my name", "is Mattia"]

First of all, I perform an operation of stamming and cleaning the fulltext and the filters, applying regex and replace.

```
document.snippet.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "");
filter.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Z0-9]/ig, "");
```

So now I can avoid various false positives such as the mismatch between "Mattia" and "mattia" etc...

At this point the answer can be trivial: I just scroll the list of filters and use the "include" string method. But suppose you have "mat" instead of "mattia" as a filter. Include uses substring, so it would return true in any case.

In my context, I have some objects called "sections" numbered through romanic numbering (i, ii, iii, ...) contained within the fulltext. So, where a "section i" filter is applied, the method in question must return false if present "... section ii ...", "... section iii ...".

I almost forgot, all filters must be satisfied, so if even one does not match, the method must return false.

I hope I've made the problem as clear as I can.

Comment: Sounds like you should just be using regex.

Comment: The filters are not static, but are entered by a user. So we can see it as a textual search but with perfect matching

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used answer of Jan Jakub Nanista and wrote a function and added case ignorance in it.

```
checkFilters(inputString: string, filters: string[]) : boolean {
      filters.forEach((filter) => {
        const regexp = new RegExp('\\b' + filter + '\\b', 'ig');
        if(!regexp.test(inputString)){
          return false;
        }
      })
      return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a [word boundary](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Assertions) regex assertion:

```
// You can add an 'i' flag as well and you don't need to lowercase your string!
const regex = new RegExp('\\b' + filter + '\\b', 'g'); 
const match = fulltext.match(regex);
```

Just make sure that the filter does not contain any regular expression special characters :)